# Doesn't Shut Down Properly Ubuntu 16.04, Have to forcefully off the laptop

Tags: shutdown

I had recently installed ubuntu 16.04 to my acer aspire v5-573G. The problem is when i click on shut down option or either try to shut down it by sudo poweroff then it hangs showing wallpaper on the screen and i have to manually shut down my laptop. Is there any solution to this problem?